# Set Google Map to geocode a Postcode on load

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps

I am using Google Maps API to show a map based on a postcode, which then uses Google's geocoding service (https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) to convert the postcode into latitude and longitude and display the map.

The example on the Google page uses a button to activate the geocoding function, and I've used that code as a starting point. However, I don't want a button, I want to hard code the postcode in (I'll replace this with a string taken from a custom meta input later). How would I adjust this code to take the postcode that I've declared in the address variable and load it at the initial load, instead of on click of the button?

Hope this makes sense.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXX&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
                                    <script>
                                        var geocoder;
                                        var map;
                                        function initialize() {
                                          geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                                          var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
                                          var mapOptions = {
                                            zoom: 8,
                                            center: latlng,
                                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                          }
                                          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
                                        }

                                        function codeAddress() {
                                          var address = 'PO19 1DQ';
                                          geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                                            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                              map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                                              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                  map: map,
                                                  position: results[0].geometry.location
                                              });
                                            } else {
                                              alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                                            }
                                          });
                                        }

                                        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
                                    </script>
                                    <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
                                    <div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%;height:300px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call codeAddress from the bottom of the initialize() function e.g.:

```
function initialize() {
         geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
         var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         }
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
         codeAddress();
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working well. I also set the default latitude and longitude in the function to `0, 0` which stopped the map flashing up a view of another location whilst waiting for the geocoding to take place.

Answer (score 1):

Already there is **load** `eventListener`.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

so place `codeAddress()` method in it.

```
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
codeAddress();
}
```

check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8sj97/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it at initialization, because geocode is asynchronous and you won't have the localisation at that time. However you can call geocode just after initialization, and you will center as soon as the geocing is finished:

```
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  codeAddress();
}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = 'PO19 1DQ';
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Of course you could see some delay, if this is the problem then you can:

- init your webpage with hidden map div, and show it when results from geocoding are available
- start geocoding just after your page is loaded, and init map when geocoding is finished